# webpage security- moving from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, html, security, authentication, https

How do I implement HTTPS when the website is hosted on a local server?
What are the various security measures that can be used to make the communication and login secure?

Comment: C as backend? How's that?

Comment: via [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) @marekful

Answer (score 0):

`http or https` is not depend on the code what you written. its totally belongs to hosting people

you can ask your hosting providers to change the website to `https` and that will be extra cost

check this link more about [https hosting](https://askleo.com/why-cant-we-use-https-for-everything/) in detail

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read OWASP:
[Transport Layer Protection Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet) (to make my website secure) and 
[HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (from HTTP to HTTPS).